# iOS Apple Configurator - Remove All Apps

Tags: ios7, mdm

Is it possible to remove all Apps from an iOS 7 device.  I would only like to have one app on the iPad (My App) and remove all other apps - Calendar / Contacts etc.

Apple configurator lets me restrict some apps like camera and safari.  I would like to remove all apps.

I would not like the Single App Mode.

Comment: Hi i am also facing a similar problem , did you happen to find any solution ?? please share

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t possible unless you jailbreak.